# What are the percentages of isotopes?

Tags: stoichiometry

The average atomic mass of a sample of an element  'X' is 16.2u. What are the percentages of isotopes $\ce{^16_8X}$(atomic number = 8, atomic mass = 16) and  $\ce{^18_8X}$(atomic number = 8, atomic mass = 18) in the sample?

Comment: [The formula for finding the percentage of isotopes in an element's atomic weight?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9016/4945) Also related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10206/4945

Comment: Hey Moderators, I tried something new on this obvious candidate for `closed as OT, homework`.

Comment: Hey @TAR86, that's nice of you.

Answer (score 2):

We have two isotopes, $A,B$ with atomic masses $m_A, m_B$. We thus have two unknowns $x_A, x_B$ representing the percentage amounts of each isotope (i.e. the mole fraction), which are trivially connected as

> $$ x_A + x_B = 1 $$

We also know something about the average atomic mass $\overline{m}$, namely

> $$ x_A \cdot m_A + x_B \cdot m_B = \overline{m} $$

So we now have a system of two linear equations to plug in values and solve. Steps:

> $$ x_A = 1 - x_B $$

.

> $$ (1 - x_B ) \cdot m_A + x_B \cdot m_B = \overline{m} $$

.

> $$ x_B \cdot (m_B - m_A) = \overline{m} - m_A $$

.

> $$ x_B = \frac{\overline{m} - m_A}{m_B - m_A} $$

And plug back in the first equation.

Comment: $x_A$ representing the percentage amounts of each isotope = mole fraction?